# Passing a class instance with a private constructor (Factory Pattern) to a function

Tags: scala

In one of my Scala files I have

```
object DataObject {

    def create(...) {
        new DataObject(...)
    }

}

private case class DataObject(...) { ... }
```

using a Factory pattern. Can I not give DataObject as a input parameter to

```
object myfunction { value(in: DataObject): Double = ??? }
```

? I get the error from IntelliJ that "Cannot resolve symbol DataObject". If I remove `private` I don't get the error anymore, but I don't understand why I can't pass `DataObject` with `private`. I thought it is only about the constructor? Also what can I do to pass `DataObject` afterall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private case class DataObject(...) { ... }
```

makes the class private; If you want to make the *constructor* private:

```
case class DataObject private(...) { ... }
```